# Remove last elements from Queue list

Tags: c#

Everything is working fine except case 2. In case 2 i'm trying to remove last elements from Queue cause by default it's removing from beginning. I tried to make a Reverse list , then after removing Reverse it back to normal but it doesn't seems to be working. Here is the whole code:

```
namespace _4
    {
    class Program
      {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
      Queue<string> que = new Queue<string>();
      int menu;

     do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Add element");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Remove last element");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Find element");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Info");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Clear");
            Console.WriteLine("0 - Exit");

            Console.Write("Menu: ");
            menu = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (menu)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    Console.Write("How much elements?");

                    int cik = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    for (int i = 0; i < cik; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("How much elements?: ");
                        string cipars = Console.ReadLine();

                        que.Enqueue(cipars);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                break;

                case 2: // nestrada
                {
                    Console.Write("How much elements starting from last?");
                    int skaits = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    que.Reverse();

                    for (int i = 0; i < skaits; i++)
                    {
                        que.Dequeue();
                    }

                    que.Reverse();


                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                break;
                case 3:
                {
                    Console.Write("Ievadiet elementu: ");
                    string elements = Console.ReadLine();

                    int numurs = 0;

                    if (que.Contains(elements))
                    {
                        foreach (string item in que)
                        {
                            if (item==elements)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Elementa index ir {0}",numurs);
                            }
                            numurs++;
                        }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("shada elementa nav.");
                    }
                }
                break;
                case 4:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Elementu skaits: {0}",que.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    foreach (var item in que)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }
                break;
                case 5:
                {
                    que.Clear();
                }
                break;
            }
        } while (menu != 0);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working"...exactly how is it not working?

Comment: it does not Reverse at all. It just removes the first element from the list. p.s why do i keep getting minuses for topic? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `Reverse` method alter the list or return a new list with the beggining element removed ?

Comment: If you want to access the items at the end of the queue you shouldn't be using a queue in the first place; you should be using a data structure that is designed to be manipulated from both ends, such as a Deque.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Double Ended Queue? An implementation can be [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11754/A-Deque-Class-in-C)

However, what you can do the below to in-place get the first element

```
object RemoveLast(Queue q) {
object first = q.Peek();
object current = null;
while (true) {
    current = q.Dequeue();
    if (q.Peek() == first) {
        break;
    }
    q.Enqueue(current);
}
return current;
}
```

function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808852/remove-the-last-element-in-a-queue)

Answer (score 1):

`Reverse()` is a LINQ method, not a method provided by the `Queue` class. It is using the `Queue` as an `IEnumerable` input sequence and returns a **new** `IEnumerable` with the element order reversed.

So calling `que.Reverse()` will do exactly **nothing** in your code (not even waste CPU cycles).

You cannot remove the last element from a queue. the only thing you can do is to create a new queue from which the last element is omitted.

```
que = new Queue<string>(que.Take(queue.Count - 1));
```

This is pretty inefficient and you may want to think twice if there may not be a better way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse is a function.  You have to assign the new queue to a variable and use the new variable.

var reveredQueue = que.Reverse();

I wouldn't use a queue if you want to remove entries from both sides.  Try using an array.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this here with four extension methods on the Queue class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862509/2634050
Again maybe you should not be using a Queue in the first place, but for my use case I had to leave the existing code intact.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Stack(T) class which is LIFO, check the Push() and Pop() methods.
it might help you.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx